# PSYCOPG2 - Paginação

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, paginação, driver

Na busca por como fazer paginação usando psycopg2 descobri os atributos [cursor.itersize](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.itersize) e [cursor.arraysize](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.arraysize), e os métodos[cursor.fetchmany()](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchmany) e [cursor.scroll()](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.scroll)

Queria verificar com o pessoal aqui se meu entendimento está correto sobre esses métodos e atributos.
`fetchmany()` retorna muitas linhas, cuja quantidade pode ser passado como parâmetro.
`scroll()` pelo que entendi serve para rolar o cursor para alguma posição dentre as linhas carregadas pela consulta, mas não entendi o parâmetro que ele recebe.
Já o atributo `itersize` pelo que entendi, controla a quantidade de linhas que o cursor deve receber do banco. Talvez por trás o driver esteja fazendo uso do parâmetro `LIMIT` do postgresql que limita a quantidade de linhas que deve ser retornada pela consulta.
O atributo `arraysize` define a quantidade de linhas que será retornado pelo método `fetchmany()`. Não entendi a finalidade desse atributo no objeto sendo que o método `fetchmany()` já recebe um parâmetro para definir isso.

Eu preciso exibir as linhas de uma tabela em um componente gui table, de alguma api gráfica que não decidi ainda. Mas acho que é mais indicado que eu faça uso desses atributos e métodos para criar uma paginação, pois criar um objeto `cursor` com todos os dados de uma tabela que tenha muitos registros pode consumir muitos recursos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

em Python usamos uma máxima: "premature optimization is the root of all evil": 
Você não sabe, e não tem como saber a priori, antes de seu sistema funcionar se vai ter um gargalo de memória ou de I/O aí.

Mais ainda, você está usando um conector de banco que está sendo desenvolvido há varios anos, e tem grande potencial para usar as melhores práticas em Python, que envolvem sim, buscar resultados de forma "lazy" - isso é, busca resultados apenas a medida que são necessários.

Então a recomendação é acreditar que os parâmetros padrão do `fetchmany` vão ser bons na maior parte dos casos, e usar seus resultados da forma recomendada no Python: como um iterador.

```
for result in cursor.fetchmany():
      # your code here
```

Dessa forma, você deixa o trabalho de trazer uma quantidade ótima de registros para o conector, e trabalha com um resultado por vez. Depois de pronto o código, vocẽ pode fazer testes de benchmark, carga e uso de memória para ver como isso está indo - e aí sim se preocupar com esses parâmetros.

Disclaimer: já vi gente ter problemas com o fetchmany numa versão antiga de um conector para o MySQL - naquele caso, a implementação interna era realmente infantil e foi muito melhor para a pessoa pegar todos os resultados de uma única vez, numa lista do que usar uma interação como a acima. Mas acredito que no caso do psycopg2, o fetchmany esteja melhor.

Se você desejar uma paginação do seu lado, pode fazer isso de forma simples criando um iterator de Python, que independa da paginação do lado do banco: pode fazer assim:

```
def get_paged_results(cursor, limit=50):
    while True:
        page = list(cursor.fetchmany(limit))
        if not page:
              break
        yield page

...
for page in get_paged_results(cursor):
     ....
```

Comment: Então, eu não tenho preferência por onde fazer a paginação. Pensei em nível de banco para não gerar um cursor monstruoso cheio de registros, levando em conta que será uma aplicação cliente servidor o consumo na rede também será grande no caso de uma tabela muito inchada. Você tem razão quanto a otimização prematura, porém estou certo que os registros nessa tabela serão muitos, já que um novo registro será inserido a cada transação. Então ela crescerá gradativamente e logo, terá milhares de registros. Queria deixar isso tratado para não ter que mexer depois.

Comment: Eu poderia fazer essa paginação através de SQL direto, mas se o psycopg2 tem features para fazer isso eu prefiro.
Por isso queria conhecer melhor esses métodos e atributos que citei, pois me parece que eles servem justamente para isso.
Se possível com exemplos.

Comment: Especial o atibuto `itersize` e o metodo `scroll()` pois eles parecem ser exatamente o que procuro.

Comment: Opa joão, relendo seu comentário e lendo novamente a doc acho que talvez entendi o que você quis dizer. Pelo que entendi, por padrão psycopg2 trás 2000 registros do banco, numero esse definido no atributo `Cursor.itersize`.
Quando você diz "buscar resultados de forma "lazy" - isso é, busca resultados apenas a medida que são necessários." Vc quer dizer que se eu precisar de mais registros o próprio driver se encarregará de buscar?

Comment: Exatamente - o próprio driver pega mais resultados a medida que você os consome (acabei de checar o código fonte do Psicopg2 e ele faz isso mesmo)